# How to load a model of Tensorflow over 2GiB, with C++ interface?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

When applying TF model with its C++ interface, `freeze_graph` operations, for the graph file and the cpk file, are required. This operation will then generate a dumped binary protobuffer file.

However, protobuffer does not support to dump a file that is larger than 2GiB.

In this case, what's the right way to load a big model in TF, with its C++ interface? Any clues will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can still load a model if you don't freeze the graph and use savedmodel.